# How to send a custom command to an NFC tag on iOS?

Tags: ios, nfc, core-nfc

I have a tag that conforms to the ISO 14443-4 format. I need to send a hex command 30 4F (read block 79) to it. How can I achieve that? I am trying to use `NFCTagReaderSession` with `tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCTag])`, but I have no idea how to send a hex command with it, and the official documentation did not help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What happened is my ISO-1443 NTAG213TT tag (with a tamper seal) was detected by `NFCTagReaderSession` as a MiFare tag of type `NFCMiFareFamily.unknown`. I was able to send "30 01" command using NFC Tools app, but I needed to be able to do the same in code. What worked is the `sendMiFareCommand` method. I'm posting a snippet below:

```swift
func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCTag]) {
    guard let firstTag = tags.first else { return }
    session.connect(to: firstTag) { (error: Error?) in
        if error != nil {
            session.invalidate(errorMessage: "Connection error. Please try again.")
            return
        }

        print("Connected to a tag!")

        if case let .miFare(miFareTag) = tag {
            let hexCommand: [UInt8] = [0x30, 0x01]     // 30 01 hex command
            if #available(iOS 14, *) {
                miFareTag.sendMiFareCommand(commandPacket: Data(hexCommand)) { (result: Result<Data, Error>) in
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let response):
                        let hexResponse: [String] = response.map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }   // make an array of hex strings
                        if hexResponse.count == 16 {
                            let firstTamperBlock = hexResponse[3] // e.g. "4f"
                            let secondTamperBlock = hexResponse[4]  // e.g. "00"

                            // you can inspect any block in the response by accessing hexResponse array elements
                        }
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print("Read tag error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        completion(nil)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                miFareTag.sendMiFareCommand(commandPacket: Data(hexCommand)) { (response: Data, optionalError: Error?) in
                    guard let error = optionalError else {
                        print("response: \(response)")
                        return
                    }
                    print("Read tag error: \(error.localizedDescription)")

                }
            }
        } else {
            fatalError("Tag wasn't recognized as MiFare")
        }
    }
}
```

I initially thought I needed to make my tag recognizable as an `.iso7816` type in order to successfully send any commands, but this turned out not to be the case. I also didn't have to add any AIDs (Application Identifiers) to the `plist`.

Comment: NTAG 213 TagTamper is not a TagType 4, so neither confirming to ISO 14443-4 nor iso7816.